# Error al Intentar habilitar HTTPS/SSL en un proyecto usando SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-tool-suite

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo de https, habilitando HTTPS/SSL en Spring Tool Suite en un SpringBoot, he seguido la forma de hacerlo de varios sitios web, de algunos videos de youtube y tengo el mismo error **APPLICATION FAILED  TO START** seguido de este texto: *Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.*

Lo he vuelto a hacer ya varias veces desde cero pero no encuentro que estare haciendo mal. He buscado ya el error que tengo pero no me ayuda mucho y no soluciona que es lo que ocurre.

Para hacer mi archivo .p12 use el siguiente comando:
`.\keytool -genkey -alias bootsecurity -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore bootsexurity.p12 -validity 3650`
cree mi proyecto de spring boot y configure el archivo de application.properties con lo siguiente:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store= src/main/resources/bootsecurity.p12
server.ssl.key-password=security
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=bootsecurity
```

cree mi proyecto de java con el siguiente codigo:

```
package com.tic.httpsexample;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloResource {
    
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

pero me aparece el error antes mencionado. Segui investigando otras formas pero igual al hacer esta parte del proyecto en java me marca los mismo errores. Al compilar el programa se inicia normal y despues presenta el error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-15 00:39:32.298  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.h.HttpsExampleApplication            : Starting HttpsExampleApplication on LAPTOP-EIJJNNJC with PID 20404 (C:\Users\12345\Desktop\https-example\target\classes started by Adrian in C:\Users\12345\Desktop\https-example)
2020-06-15 00:39:32.303  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.h.HttpsExampleApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-15 00:39:32.396  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-06-15 00:39:32.396  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-06-15 00:39:34.375  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-15 00:39:34.411  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-15 00:39:35.471  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2020-06-15 00:39:35.483  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-15 00:39:35.484  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-06-15 00:39:35.652  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-15 00:39:35.652  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3256 ms
2020-06-15 00:39:35.936  WARN 20404 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-06-15 00:39:35.943  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-15 00:39:35.975  INFO 20404 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-15 00:39:35.990 ERROR 20404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

¿Qué estaré haciendo mal? ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar o asesorar sobre este tema? Ya no se donde mas consultar para poder hacer funcionar esto

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con HTTPS o SSL, lo que no encuentra es la conexión a base de datos (el Datasource) porque no se especifica URL. Y dice que esto se ha detectado al intentar crear una instancia de "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"

Comment: Es lo que veia en algunos sitios cuando buscaba mi error pero nunca me soluciono el problema que tuve con lo que ellos mencionaban que podria ser la solucion. Incluso en donde me fui guiando para hacerlo, nunca hicieron mencion sobre el Datasource ni presentaron problemas con ello. Es por eso que no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o que es lo que debo hacer en realidad

Answer (score 0):

es posible que dentro de las dependencias tengas algo que implique acceso a la base de datos, tal como **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**. Si no vas a usar una base de datos en este proyecto, deberías quitar esta dependencía de tu pom.xml, si vas a usar una base de datos, debes poner los parametros del datasource, por ejemplo:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/mydb
    spring.datasource.username=user
    spring.datasource.password=password
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```